# Need help identifying notation, groups, $(G:1)$

Tags: abstract-algebra

> 1. Let $G$ be a finite group and let $p$ be a prime integer.
>
> (a) Show that if $p$ divides $(G:1)$, then $G$ contains an element of order $p$. (You may assume this holds if $G$ is abelian)

My only question is what does the notation $(G:1)$ refer to? I am preparing for qualifying exams, still not an official graduate student yet but I saw this in one of the past algebra qualifying exams. From my experience, the little bit I have had, in abstract algebra, it would seem to me that $(G:1)$ could in some way be referring to the order of the group but I kind of doubt this as I am not sure where the $1$ comes from. I am guessing it is something I haven't heard of before or I just haven't seen the notation for it if I have.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, then $(G:H)$ is a notation for the index of $H$ in $G$. So $(G:1)$ is just the order of $G$.

Comment: Okay thank you, I have seen the index notation, I just wasn't sure what the $1$ meant.

Comment: Presumably, the 1-element subgroup of $G$.

Answer (score 4):

Other alternative notations may be found as follows:

- $[G:H]$, for example in Rotman's *An introduction to the Theory of groups*.
- $|G:H|$, for example in Gorenstein's *Finite groups*.

Comment: Thank you. I guess it was oversight on my part, we used $[G:H]$ in my textbook. Thanks though this is helpful